# OpenERP 7 absorbing tax

Tags: odoo, gstreamer

Need assistant in OpenERP 7 Tax absorbing.

I need to know if it possible to do so in OpenERP 7 if yes, where should I add/deduct the absorbing of tax formula.

1. Sales/Pricelist
2. Accounting/Taxes

If it supposed to be here, what will be the proper calculation or formula. Tried all kinds of calculation.

My intention is to sell a product which will be absorbing Tax of 7% and the end of the total price still show the actual GST amount on the quotation/invoice without deducting the total price.

Example:

Product   Qty     UOM     Taxes   UP     Disc(%)   Subtotal
Book       1      Unit     7%    10.00    0         10.00

```
                              Untaxed price  = $10.00
                               Tax 7%        = $0.70
                               Total         = $10.00
```

Above is the exact thing I wish to appear on the printed Quotation/Invoice. I've tried avery possible configuration and calculation to make it appear that way.

If these not possible, will there be any other possibility in OpenERP that to allow Tax absorbing and the end of calculation (total) instead of the standard "Per line" and "global"

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I think, There is no such feature in OpenERP of tax absorbing but you can customize your code to achieve it. Right now, on tax, There is one field 'Tax included in Price' but if you will tick it and check, Total will be same 10.00 but it will also change Untaxed amount and Tax too. So its useless for you as per your requirements.

There is also no feature by that you can apply tax globally instead of per line. You also need to customize it by adding a new field tax in Quotation/Invoice and removing it from Order/Invoice lines and calculate it in Tax field.